# Adding VOIP functionality on an existing iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, voip, callkit

I have an existing app which is categorized as a "Health and Fitness" app.  I would like add functionality to do video calls (using a 3rd party sdk like Skype or Twilio) with this app and want to use CallKit to launch this app if it isn't running.  Is it as simple as using the Skype / Twilio sdk along with CallKit? Or do I have to register my app in a different category with Apple to do this?

Is there anything that I need to consider to add VOIP functionality to an existing app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CallKit is tricky and notoriously poorly documented, but [this post](https://sendbird.com/blog/make-local-calls-with-callkit) should help you with it.

To get up and running, check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pe4IphfJzI), which shows how to get set up.  It is geared towards Android, but you can follow the same steps using the [iOS quickstart app](https://github.com/sendbird/quickstart-calls-ios).